# In Lucene/Solr what is the difference between Join and BlockJoin?

Tags: join, solr, lucene

Join is described as pseudo-Join, because it's more equivalent to an SQL inner-query.
Whereas BlockJoin [is described](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/searching-relational-content-with.html) as more like a SQL join but requiring a sophisticated indexing schema, one that anticipates all the possible joins you'd want to make.
Could someone explain the difference between these features in terms of how to implement them at index time and query time. And what are the  implications for performance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think blockjoinquery is a Solr function. I think its Lucene feature.

The solr join doesn't score documents in the from query and it doesn't return combined results. So its best used as a filter query. This will allow the main query.to score.

Block join on the other hand does use scoring and returns both results.( not 100% sure)

You can also use querytime join. This has serval scoring options. This is also a lucene feature but doesn't require special indexing blocks. I've used this in combination with a solr query parser plugin. The performance is a bit lower then blockjoin but it Works.

I have only used solr join and querytimejoin  So I can't really say much about blockjoin.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, BlockJoin is for joining against nested/child documents within the same core. Join is for joining against a separate core.